# file not found error message

Tags: unix, cygwin, file-not-found

I am using cygwin for running .sh file for a project that i downloaded from the internet.
I have a config file and from where config is i am typing:
sh C:/Newfolder/project/filename.sh 
and i am getting this message:
"C:/Newfolder/project/configure: line 83: .: config: file not found".
configure has the following instructions:

```
#!/bin/bash
check_or_create_dir()
{
  if [[ ! -d "${!1}" ]]; then
  if [[ -e "${!1}" ]]; then
    echo "Error: $1 should be a directory. Check your config"
    exit 1
  else
    mkdir "${!1}"
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      echo "Error: $1 doesn't exist and cannot be created. Check your config"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
fi
}

check_file()
{
    if [[ ! -f $1 ]]; then
        echo "Error: missing file $1. Check your config"
        exit 1
    fi
}

check_var()
{
    if [[ -z ${!1} ]];
    then
        echo "Error: $1 not set in config. Check your config"
        exit 1
    fi

    export $1
}

check_exe()
{
    if (which "$1" >& /dev/null); then
        return 0
    else
        echo "Error: missing required program: $1"
        exit 1
    fi
}

if [[ -e config ]];
then
    . config
else
    echo "Error: no config file in current directory"
    exit 0
fi

check_var "DECKARD_DIR"
check_var "FILE_PATTERN"
check_var "SRC_DIR"

check_var "VECTOR_DIR"
check_or_create_dir "VECTOR_DIR"
check_var "CLUSTER_DIR"
check_or_create_dir "CLUSTER_DIR"
check_var "TIME_DIR"
check_or_create_dir "TIME_DIR"

check_var "VGEN_EXEC"
check_file "$VGEN_EXEC"
check_var "GROUPING_EXEC"
check_file "$GROUPING_EXEC"
check_var "CLUSTER_EXEC"
check_file "$CLUSTER_EXEC"
check_var "POSTPRO_EXEC"
check_file "$POSTPRO_EXEC"

check_var "MIN_TOKENS"
check_var "STRIDE"
#check_var "DISTANCE"
check_var "SIMILARITY"
check_var "GROUPING_S"
#check_var "GROUPING_D"
#check_var "GROUPING_C"

check_exe "which"
check_exe "env"
check_exe "python"
check_exe "awk"
check_exe "sed"
check_exe "grep"
check_exe "find"
check_exe "bash"
check_exe "cat"
check_exe "touch"
check_exe "head"
check_exe "tail"
#check_exe "time"

# For parallel processing
if [[ -z "${MAX_PROCS}" ]];
then
   echo "Warning: MAX_PROCS not set in config. Assume 0"
   MAX_PROCS=0
fi
export MAX_PROCS
```

Comment: the error message line number doesn't "line-up" with any reference to file `config` . Were you editing your code (moving stuff around) when testing this? Did you paste your code to http://shellcheck.net ? (It looks OK, but I can't spend the time to look thru a 100 line script). Good luck.!

Comment: try running in the directory. `cd /cygdrive/c/Newfolder/project/` and `./filename.sh`

Comment: the code i have says:                                                                                 
if [[ -e config ]];
then
    . config
else
    echo "Error: no config file in current directory"
    exit 0                                                                                                                      while the error message i am getting is: configure: line 83: .: config: file not found

Comment: line 83 corrosponds to .config

Comment: maybe you want `. .config`? or `. config` in your code? in either case, the error message is not lying to you, you need to figure out as @matzeri has commented, do you use `cd /path/to/cfgDir ` and/or `/path/to/cfgDir/config` . Good luck.